# Webpack mixing up default and named imports

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, react-bootstrap

While updating some deps (`react-bootstrap`) I ran into a react error

`You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Compiling the same code with other setups (storybook, create react app, codesandbox, ...) doesn't show the issue.

Looks like the component we import (`react-bootstrap/Dropdown`), imports another component (`react-overlays/Dropdown`) which causes the problem.

I tracked the error down to this line which does NOT get outputted:
`/* harmony import */ var react_overlays_Dropdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(react_overlays_Dropdown__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__);`

Instead, the non-working code uses the `..._MODULE_4__['default']` syntax, which fails and raises the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searches I found out the problem...

Changing this

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
    }
};
```

to this

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    }
};
```

solves the problem.